# $cookieStore is undefined error in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to store a variable in `cookieStore` to access it in another js file. When I use  `$cookieStore.put`, it gives me error saying `$cookieStore is undefined`.

My code:

```
var classFinder= angular.module('classFinder',['onsen.directives', 'ngTouch','ngCookies']);
classFinder.controller('courseController',['$cookieStore', function($scope,$window,$http,$cookieStore){
 /**cookies**/
 $cookieStore.put('myFavorite','oatmeal');
 // Get cookie
 var favoriteCookie = $cookieStore.get('myFavorite');
 // Removing a cookie
 $cookieStore.remove('myFavorite');
 }]);
```

I have included the script of angular-cookies in my html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at how you define your controller:

```
['$cookieStore', function($scope, $window, $http, $cookieStore)
```

You're supposed to have as many strings in the array, and in the same order, as you have arguments in the function. So it should be

```
['$scope', '$window', '$http', '$cookieStore', 
     function($scope, $window, $http, $cookieStore)
```

Comment: thanks dude !! solved it.. just 1 question what do u call those things that u just added? is these dependencies?

Comment: Yes, those are dependencies. Note that this array notation is only needed to be able to minify the Java code. You can avoid it, and still be able to minify, by using a tool that does this transformation for you before minifying: [ng-annotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-annotate).

Comment: @ChetanShah the way to thank people here is by upvoting their answer when it is useful, and by accepting it (clicking the "check" icon next to the answer) when it solves your problem and is the best answer you've received.